# VBA - How to avoid copy paste code in select-case statements?

Tags: vba, case-statement

I have some a select-case statement that runs one of three functions depending on a three-letter acronym. With dozens of possible acrynoms, the code becomes very repetitive (see an abstract example below). Is there a way to shorten this so there's one only one case that calls function1 and only one case that calls function2?

```
Select varAcronym
  Case "ABC"
    function1
  Case "DEF"
    function1
  Case "GHI"
    function1
  Case "JKL"
    function2
  Case "MNO"
    function2
  Case "PQR"
    function2
End Select
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... I realized I can do this with just a few if statements. But, I am still curious how to do this with select-case statements.

Comment: I wont post as an answer as I can't test - you might be able to do `Case 'ABC' To 'GHI'`. It'll be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to add "Case" after "Select"

```
Select Case varAcronym
  Case "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"
    function1
  Case "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"
    function2
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one case condition on the `case` line

```
Select varAcronym
  Case "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"
    function1
  Case "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"
    function2
End Select
```